# latexmk with glossaries in MS Windows

Tags: latexmk

I am using latexmk and trying to get it to successfully compile the glossaries. I used the script in CTAN (http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/support/latexmk/example_rcfiles/glossary_latexmkrc) but it doesn't seem to work in Windows. Here is the error messages:
[image]

It seems to try to use `./` as the directory but in windows that would be `.\` so I believe that is why it is not working.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: At first glance it looks like `makeglossaries` is doing that `chdir`.

Comment: If I call make glossaries from shell it works, it only fails when it goes through latexmk

Comment: Latexmk maintainer here. Normally, using forward slashes as directory separators under Windows works as well as the standard backslashes.  (However on a command line to cmd.exe, they need to be quoted, but that's not relevant here.)  The error message from runscript.tlu shows that latexmk in fact passed ".\" not "./" to `makeglosssaries`.  There's a line in `makeglossaries` that changes the backslash to forward slash.  Let me see if I can reproduce this; I have a fix if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turns out to be a problem with filename quoting in the arguments to `makeglossaries`.  The simplest fix is to modify the code in the `latexmkrc` from what is given in the `latexmk` documentation to

```
add_cus_dep( 'acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
$clean_ext .= " acr acn alg glo gls glg";
sub makeglossaries {
    my ($name, $path) = fileparse( $$Psource );
    return system "makeglossaries", "-d", $path, $name;
}
```

A better method is to use

```
add_cus_dep( 'acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
add_cus_dep( 'glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglossaries' );
$clean_ext .= " acr acn alg glo gls glg";
sub makeglossaries {
    my ($base_name, $path) = fileparse( $_[0] );
    pushd $path;
    my $return = system "makeglossaries", $base_name;
    popd;
    return $return;
}
```